# Discovery of Offons

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Physicists at Cern have detected the elusive "offon" pair in laboratory.
But still observing the accelerator that contains the 2 offons.

Based on singularity principle in which points to existence of the 2 offons,
they believed that the entire Universe can only have 2 offons (a pair).

Einstein confirmed the unchanging offon pair in his General relativity.
While in String theory the occurance of 2 offons are fixed in space.

If "offon" is the answer, what is the question?

Comment: `knowledge` tag in play here?

Comment: @Forklift- no need

Comment: "How frequently?"

Comment: The original puzzle is generally pretty poor English, but I can't fix it without pretty much rewriting it. Anyone else have a go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Earlier remarks incorrect; therefore, rendering correction:

> "offon" means a pair of **R**s, at any distance?

Physicists at Cern have detected the elusive "offon" pair in laboratory.

> labo**r**ato**r**y.

But still observing the accelerator that contains the 2 offons.

> accele**r**ato**r**.

Based on singularity principle in which points to existence of the 2 offons, They believed that the entire Universe can only have 2 offons (a pair).

> singula**r**ity p**r**inciple / the enti**r**e Unive**r**se

Einstein confirmed the unchanging offon pair in his General relativity.

> Gene**r**al **r**elativity.

While in String theory the occurance of 2 offons are fixed in space.

> St**r**ing theo**r**y

If "offon" is the answer, what is the question?

> "From the outside, how do you **r**eset the collide**r**?"

Comment: Almost..but the distances are not that close.

Answer (score 2):

It may be

> My router isn't working, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The question might be:

> What are the two states in a binary system, (1 or 0 representing off or on)?